# Parsear datos de un objeto dentro de un JSON en Angular2

Tags: json, array, angularjs-2.0, object, angular-datatables

He seguido este tutorial para crear una tabla con un *JSON* en *Angular 2*.

http://4dev.tech/2016/09/creating-an-angular2-datatable-from-scratch/

Mi duda es, si tuviera un *JSON* de este tipo:

```
{"visitas": [{
    "_id": "586b5d313406cd103c3f38d5",
    "fecha":"01-ene-2017",
    "paciente": {
        "_id": "586b525dcd09c319a04d7da1",
        "edad": "25",
        "nombre": "Paciente1"
    },
    "diagnostico": "Diagnostico de visita",
}]}
```

¿Cómo parseo el `nombre` o la `edad` de mi paciente en la tabla?

Esta es la vista de mi componente:

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th *ngFor="let column of columns">{{column.header}}</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody *ngFor="let row of getData()">
    <tr>
      <td *ngFor="let column of columns">{{row[column.value]}}</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

... y mi selector `datatable` en otra vista es este:

```
<md-card>
  <h3>Tabla Dinamica de Pacientes</h3>
  <datatable [dataset]=visitas [enableFilter]=true >
    <column [value]="'fecha'" [header]="'Fecha'"></column>
    <column [value]="'paciente'" [header]="'Paciente'"></column>
    <column [value]="'edad'" [header]="'Edad'"></column>
    <column [value]="'diagnostico'" [header]="'Diagnostico'"></column>
    <column [value]="'_id'" [header]="'Id'"></column>
  </datatable>
</md-card>
```

... pero obtengo que en el nombre de mi `paciente` hay un objeto:

```
  "Fecha"   -   "Paciente"  -  "Edad" -   "Diagnóstico"     -          "ID"
"01-ene-2017" "[object Object]"      "Diagnóstico de visita" "586B5D313406CD103C3F38D5"
```

... y si le pongo lo siguiente, no se refleja nada.

```
<column [value]="'paciente.nombre'" [header]="'Paciente'"></column>
```

Comment: ¿Solucionaste el problema?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tienes que **inicializar** ese json a un objeto, primero creas tu **clase** del mismo en un **modelo** así:

export class Contact {
    name: string;
    last_name: string;
    email: string;

```
constructor(json?) {
  this.name = json && json.name;
  this.last_name = json && json.last_name;
  this.email = json && json.email;
}
```

}

Después ya lo utilizas en tu clase **inicializándolo**:

```
this.contact = new Contact(tuJSON);
```

Answer (score 0):

Prueba con:

```
<md-card>
  <h3>Tabla Dinamica de Pacientes</h3>
  <datatable [dataset]=visitas [enableFilter]=true >
    <column [value]="{{fecha}}" [header]="'Fecha'"></column>
    <column [value]="{{paciente.nombre}}" [header]="'Paciente'"></column>
    <column [value]="{{edad}}" [header]="'Edad'"></column>
    <column [value]="{{diagnostico}}" [header]="'Diagnostico'"></column>
    <column [value]="{{_id}}" [header]="'Id'"></column>
  </datatable>
</md-card>
```